# How to create prototype for REST api in symfony 2

Tags: php, rest, fosrestbundle, fosoauthserverbundle, symfony-2.4

Hi there for implementing the symfony2 base REST api bundle i have installed the following bundle.

- FosOauth server bundle for Oauth2.0 base authentication
- FosRest bundle for REST api creation.

now can any body suggest me how can i create generalize prototype for all REST API call response.
in json format like

```
{
    "responseType" : "[FAILED|PASSED]",
    "data" : ["RESPECTIVE DATA WILL COME HERE"],
    "errorCode" : "if any ERROR comes we can set those respective code here",
    "errorMessage": "respective error messages either in the string or array"
}
```

Thanks in advance :)